# Let $K$ be a field, $V$ a vector space and $U,W \subseteq V$ subspaces of $V$. Show that:

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, $V$ a vector space and $U,W \subseteq V$ subspaces of $V$. Show that:

*a.* $(U+W)/W \cong U /(U \cap W)$

*b.* Let $U\subseteq W\subseteq V$ then can $W/U$ be considered as subspace of $V/U$ and it is $$(V/U)/(W/U) \cong V/W$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem, so far? What have you tried? The more you can tell us about your efforts, the better we can gauge your experience level and familiarity, and tailor our answers to your needs. Also, many here are more willing to help people who show effort in the first place.

Comment: Writing \stackrel{\text{\$\sim\$}}= instead of \stackrel{\sim}= is weird, but I changed it to \cong. Contrast $a\stackrel{\text{$\sim$}}= b$ versus $a\cong b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: For part a, consider a composition of natural linear maps $$U\hookrightarrow U+W\twoheadrightarrow (U+W)/W.$$ what is the kernel of this composition? What is its image?

For part b, can you find a linear map $W/U\hookrightarrow V/U$? What about $V/U\twoheadrightarrow V/W$? What are the kernels of these maps? Their images?

Let me know if you're stuck with any of these, or if you just want to check that you're on the right track.